# Area of a flat region

Tags: integration, analysis

I need to know if the result of the following integral is right or wrong.

Compute the area of the set $A=B \cap C$ where 
$B=\left \{ (x,y): x^2+y^2\geqslant 1 \right \}, \quad C=\left \{ (x,y): x^2-2x+y^2\leqslant 0 \right \}$

using polar coordinates $\Phi: \left \{x=\rho \cos \theta, y= \rho \sin \theta \right\}$, the polar region is
$D=\left \{ (\rho, \theta): 1 \leqslant \rho \leqslant 2 \cos \theta, -\frac{\pi}{3} \leqslant \theta \leqslant \frac{\pi}{3}  \right \}$ and $A=\Phi (D)$. Then

$m(A)=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \int_{1}^{2 \cos \theta} \rho \, d\rho d\theta =\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} (4 \cos^2 \theta -1) \, d\theta \\= \frac{1}{2}[2(\sin \theta \cos \theta + \theta)-\theta]^{\frac{\pi}{3}}_{-\frac{\pi}{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{\pi}{3}$

the problem is that in my professor’s notes the result is   $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}+\frac{\pi}{6}$
but I believe it’s wrong..

Comment: Your answer is correct. Probably your professor just did the upper half, and forgot to multiply by $2$ at the end.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!